# SSH connection on boot

Tags: ssh

I would like to connect  on boot my RaspberryPI (local) with my Mac(remote) trough SSH to execute a command on Mac . I have set the SSH connection without password (the connection is established by the same RSA-key) moreover I have set on two machine a static IP address . I have written this script.

```
# ! /bin/sh 
ssh davide@192.168.1.12 touch /user/davide/desktop/try
```

I have put this script with right permission into /etc/init.d.
I tried with  /etc/rc.local 
I also tried to put it inside /etc/network/if-up.d and I have edited the /etc/network/interfaces with a post-up command to my script. But these method don't work.

Comment: have you tried putting quotations around the command part? does this ssh command work normally if you run it manually? If the command is ok I'd look at [instructions on running a command on boot](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up) next

Comment: You might need to use `ssh -i` to set the identify file location, otherwise it won't know which key to use.